# List of Strings - golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a list of Strings in golang. I'm looking up the package [container/list](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#example_) but I don't know how to put in a string. I tried several times, but 0 result.

Should I use another thing instead of lists?
Thanks in advance.

edit: Don't know why are you rating this question with negatives votes...

Comment: unless you have a specific need for a doubly-linked-list, you almost always want a `[]string` slice instead.

Comment: Use slice instead. Or put some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code to the package you linked, it seems that the `List` type holds a list of `Element`s. Looking at `Element` you'll see that it has one exported field called `Value` which is an `interface{}` type, meaning it could be literally anything: `string`, `int`, `float64`, `io.Reader`, etc.

To answer your second question, you'll see that `List` has a method called `Remove(e *Element)`. You can use it like this:

```
fmt.Println(l.Len()) // prints: 4

// Iterate through list and print its contents.
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    if e.Value == "4" {
        l.Remove(e) // remove "4"
    } else {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}

fmt.Println(l.Len()) // prints: 3
```

By and large, Golang documentation is usually pretty solid, so you should always check there first.

https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the exact example you linked, and changing the ints to strings works for me:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new list and put some numbers in it.
    l := list.New()
    e4 := l.PushBack("4")
    e1 := l.PushFront("1")
    l.InsertBefore("3", e4)
    l.InsertAfter("2", e1)

    // Iterate through list and print its contents.
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.